# Trying to get program to end when the word "Done" is typed

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working with a Java program on Eclipse. The program gets the "txt" file name from the user and print out the number of lines in that "txt" file ("There are "x" lines in the file"). If the "txt" file does not exist, it should print out "That file does not exist"

I am trying to get the program to keep looping, asking for a file name regardless of whether the last entry resulted in an error or not, until the user types "Done".

This is the code I am editing. There are 2 classes total. This is the first (ProcessFile.java):

```
// ProcessFile.java

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * 
 * This class will ask the user for a text file
 * name, open that file, and print all the lines
 * of the file and how many lines there are.
 * 
 *
 */

public class ProcessFile {

/**
 * This method prompts the user to enter a
 * file name and returns it.
 * 
 * @return A String containing a file name.
 */
public static String getFileName()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
    String fileName;
    FileReader reader;

    do
    {
        System.out.println( "Please enter a file name to open: " );
        fileName = in.nextLine();

        try
        {
            reader = new FileReader( fileName );
        }
        catch( FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "That file does not exist." );
            reader = null;
        }
    }
    while ( reader == null );

    in.close();

    try
    {
        reader.close();
    }
        catch ( IOException e )
    {
            System.out.println( e );
    }

    return fileName;    
}

/**
 * This method takes an ArrayList of Strings and prints each
 * element of the ArrayList, one per line, as well as the
 * number of items in the ArrayList.
 * 
 * @param lines
 */
public static void printInformation( ArrayList<String> lines )
{
    for ( String line : lines )
        System.out.println( line );

    System.out.println( "There are " + lines.size() + " lines in the file." );
}

public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    String fileName;
    FileManager fileInfo;
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    fileName = getFileName( );

    fileInfo = new FileManager( fileName );

    try 
    {
        lines = fileInfo.readLines();
    }
    catch( FileNotFoundException e ) 
    {
        System.out.println( e );
    }   

    printInformation( lines );
}
}
```

This is the second class (FileManager.java):

```
// FileManager.java

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class will manage the interaction with the
 * file for the ProcessFile class.
 * 
 *
 */
public class FileManager 
{
    private String fileName;

    public FileManager( String file )
    {
        fileName = file;
    }

    /**
     * This function will read the file stored in 
     * fileName and return an ArrayList made up of
     * the lines of the file.
     * 
     * @return An ArrayList containing the file's lines.
     */
    public ArrayList<String> readLines( ) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileReader fileIn = new FileReader( fileName );
        Scanner in = new Scanner( fileIn );

        while ( in.hasNextLine() )
        {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            lines.add( line );
        }

        in.close();
        return lines;
    }
}
```

For the "if the user types 'Done', end the program" part, I looked up some stuff and have included it in the code below. Not sure if it is right but I got no error when I typed that part in. This are the changes I've made (I put comments by the parts I changed):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * 
 * This class will ask the user for a text file
 * name, open that file, and print all the lines
 * of the file and how many lines there are.
 * 
 *
 */
public class ProcessFile {

 /**
  * This method prompts the user to enter a
  * file name and returns it.
  * 
  * @return A String containing a file name.
  */
 public static String getFileName() // Error: This method must return a result of type String
 {
     Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
     String fileName;
     FileReader reader;
     int x = 1;

     if (System.in.equals("Done") || System.in.equals("done")) // This is the part I wasn't sure of (the one I said I looked up)
     {
         System.exit(0);
     }

     else 
     {
         while (x == 1)
         {
             System.out.println( "Please enter a file name to open: " );
             fileName = in.nextLine();

             try
             {
                 reader = new FileReader( fileName );
             }
             catch( FileNotFoundException e )
             {
                 System.out.println( "That file does not exist." );
             }


             in.close();

             try
             {
                 reader.close(); //Error: The local variable reader may not have been initialized
             }
                 catch ( IOException e )
             {
                     System.out.println( e );   
             }
             return fileName;
         }
     }
 }

 /**
  * This method takes an ArrayList of Strings and prints each
  * element of the ArrayList, one per line, as well as the
  * number of items in the ArrayList.
  * 
  * @param lines
  */
 public static void printInformation( ArrayList<String> lines )
 {
     for ( String line : lines )
         System.out.println( line );

     System.out.println( "There are " + lines.size() + " lines in the file." );
 }

 public static void main( String[] args ) 
 {
     String fileName;
     FileManager fileInfo;
     ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

     fileName = getFileName( );

     fileInfo = new FileManager( fileName );

     try 
     {
         lines = fileInfo.readLines();
     }
     catch( FileNotFoundException e ) 
     {
         System.out.println( e );
     }  

     printInformation( lines );
     getFileName(); // <--- Return to the top and get the user input again.
 }
}
```

I think I am close to getting this. Any bit of help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

---

**Edited Code (@µTheory)

```
public static String getFileName()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
    String fileName;
    FileReader reader;


    do
    {
        System.out.println( "Please enter a file name to open: " );
        fileName = in.nextLine();

        if ( in.equals("Done") || in.equals("done") )
        {
            in.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            try
            {
                reader = new FileReader( fileName ); //Error: The local variable reader may not have been initialized.
            }
            catch( FileNotFoundException e )
            {
                System.out.println( "That file does not exist." );
            }
        }

        in.close();

        try
        {
            reader.close();
        }
            catch ( IOException e )
        {
            System.out.println( e );    
        }
        return fileName;
    }
    while ( reader == null );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, `System.in` refers to an `InputStream` so your call to `System.in.equals("Done");`tries to compare a `String`and an `InputStream`and will obviously return false. Instead, call `fileName = in.nextLine();` before your `if`statement then check if `filename.equals("Done")`. And put your if statement in your `while`loop.

Now you have created an infinite loop : `while ( x == 1)` never stops because you instancied `x=1`and you never changes the value inside your loop.

I suggest that you change your loop to `while( reader == null)`as you programed before. And take out of your `while` statement and put them after the lines

```
         in.close();

         try
         {
             reader.close();//No more error
         }
             catch ( IOException e )
         {
                 System.out.println( e );   
         }
         return fileName;
```

So why ?  Because while your `reader` is `null`you can **not** close the `Scanner`that allows you to call `fileName = in.nextLine();` each iteration of the loop. And as you want to end the loop when your `reader`is not null you can **not** call `reader.close();` because by definition your `reader`object will be null and throw a `NullPointerException`.

And consider before calling `System.exit(0);` closing all your open streams such as your `Scanner`.

**EDIT:**

```
public static String getFileName()
{
Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
String fileName;
FileReader reader;


do
{
    System.out.println( "Please enter a file name to open: " );
    fileName = in.nextLine();

    if ( fileName.equals("Done") || fileName.equals("done") )
    {
        in.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    else
    {
        try
        {
            reader = new FileReader( fileName ); //Error: The local variable reader may not have been initialized.
        }
        catch( FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "That file does not exist." );
        }
    }

}
while ( reader == null );

    in.close();

    try
    {
        reader.close();
    }
        catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( e );    
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

So this the correct code. You still didn't understood that with `in.equals("Done")`you are trying to compare your `in`obejct which is an instance of `Scanner`and a `String`and as I said above, this will obvisouly return false. So it's why i replaced `in` by `fileNmae`wich represents the line entered by the user.

Then i extracted the block :

```
    in.close();

    try
    {
        reader.close();
    }
        catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( e );    
    }
    return fileName;
```

Outside of your `while` loop, as i stated above. You can not close the streams if you are still using them or if they are not yet instancied.

Comment: Do you mean I move the code in the gray square above right below the while statement?

Comment: @wandering_flame Right

Comment: Okay. I've edited the question to include the edited version of that code based on your advice (because I couldn't fit it here). Could you take one more look at it and let me know if I understood your answer properly? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm also getting one more error too. It's "reader.close( );". The error says "The local variable reader may not have been initialized." When I take the suggestion of Eclipse and initialize it to "null", I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException" error when I type "Done".

Comment: @wandering_flame I've updated the answer there is everything you need but try to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get user input from Scanner and compare it with "Done", not the `System.in` itself. `System.in` is just a **stream**, not the actual input, and you need to **read** from that stream in order to compare it.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)

String inp = s.nextLine()

if(inp.equals("Done"))
{
    //Code
}
```

And, as @DeiAndrei noted in his answer, you can use `equalsIgnoreCase` in order to, well, compare it without case sensitivity. Forgot about that and added this for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the part you are not sure about with:

```
if(in.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("done")){

    System.exit(1);
}
```

You can do a case-insensitive comparison by using equalsIgnoreCase method.
To read from the console, just use Scanner.nextLine() or any other methods you think are suitable from the Scanner class.

If you don't want to accept input like:

```
"DONE", "DoNe", etc
```

Then just compare the input String with

```
"Done" and "done"
```

as before.